# TornadoFX wizard: block move to next page until async task completed

Tags: tornadofx

I try to configure TornadoFX wizard page and one of my pages has a selection of item. This selection invokes a longer time task of loading data. Therefore on the page when selection changes I only set a kind of proxy value (of type BoardDefinition):

```
private fun loadBoard(def: BoardDefinition) {
    scope.boardDef = def
}
```

With this, I avoid to load data unnecessarily while the user makes the decision. My intention was, that only when the user decides to move on, the proxy is relaxed and the data is loaded. 
I tried the move the loading part into `onSave`, but the loading being async, the wizard moves to the next page (and that page tries to use the data still under loading):

```
override fun onSave() {
    runAsync {
        showProgress(
            "Játéktábla betöltése",
            "A játéktábla betöltése folyamatban",
            ProgressDialog.ProgressMode.INDICATOR,
            this
        )
        // This lazy initialization performs the long-time data loading
        scope.board = scope.boardDef.board
    } ui {
        ProgressDialog.hide()
        super.onSave()
    }
}
```

I have several ideas how to come over this problem. I could create a Future object and block the execution of onSave while the data is available. Or I could add a page which only loads the data and the onComplete property is set to monitor whether the load is over. Both of it looks like hacking. Is there a more elegant way to do some time consuming async task when the user presses `Next`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some unsuccessful tries, I settled the problem with this twist:

I created a loading View:

```
class LoadBoardView : View() {

    class Scope(val source: <Your source type>, var loaded: <Your loaded type>) 
        : tornadofx.Scope()

    override val scope = super.scope as Scope

    override fun onDock() {
       super.onDock()

       runAsync {
           // Do the loading into scope.loaded
       } ui {
           close()
       }
   }

}
```

This view starts the loading immediately after show and closes itself when done.

In my wizard page, I simply use blocked execution:

```
override fun onSave() {
    val loaderScope = LoadBoardView.Scope(<your id to load>)
    find<LoadBoardView>(loaderScope).apply {
        openModal( block = true)
    }
    // Get loaded value from loaderScope.loaded
    super.onSave()
}
```